# subquery having replace doesn't recognize in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

The problem is I want to put SELECT result using subquery in A_table  A_LIST column
where clause so that they can match A_TABLE 'A_List' and B_TABLE 'userList'

**A_TABLE**

```
+-------+----------+
| A_LOG |  A_List  |
+-------+----------+
| WQ-83 |    a     |
| WQ-82 |    b     |
| WQ-89 |    c     |
| WQ-85 |    d     |
| WQ-86 |    e     |
| WQ-81 |    f     |
+-------+----------+
```

**B_TABLE**

```
+----------+--------------------+
| userName |     userList       |
+----------+--------------------+
| A_PERSON | ['a','b','c','d']  |
| B_PERSON | NULL               |
+----------+--------------------+
```

b.table data looks like **['a','b','c','d']**(column name -> userList] in one column so I use replace to parsing context

```
SELECT replace(replace(userList,'[',''),']','') from Btable
```

the result look like --> **'a','b','c','d'** and Put this select query in subquery
A.table list column data seems like a,b,c in each columns

```
SELECT A_List  from A_TABLE where A_List IN(
SELECT replace(replace(userList,'[',''),']','') from B_TABLE
)
```

but this query result returns 0 data

so I try

```
SELECT  A_List  from A_TABLE where A_List IN( 'a','b','c','d');
```

it returns 4 rows -> It's correct data

```
+-------+----------+
| A_LOG |  A_List  |
+-------+----------+
| WQ-83 |    a     |
| WQ-82 |    b     |
| WQ-89 |    c     |
| WQ-85 |    d     |
+-------+----------+
```

I don't know why this query fail
What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current user list data *almost* looks like a valid JSON array, except that the values should be in double quotes, instead of single quotes.  Assuming your data looked like this:

```
["a","b","c","d"]
```

then we use the following query:

```
SELECT a.A_LOG, a.A_List
FROM A_TABLE a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM B_TABLE b
              WHERE JSON_SEARCH(b.userList, 'one', a.A_List) IS NOT NULL);
```

[image: screen capture from demo below]

### Demo

Comment: It works!! thank you so much:) !!!!  
I've been trying to solve the problem all day.